# Getting a GPU Bitcoin miner for Linux 64bit

Tags: linux, software-rec, 64-bit, bitcoin

I've just learned about the awesome world of Bitcoins. I've learned that the only way to make a decent amount of bitcoins is to "mine". However, everywhere I look, the miners are for Windows and those that have clients for Linux only support 32bit.

I'd like to be able to mine off my GPU (if possible). I have an ATI graphics card (I've heard there isn't much support for ATI, only Nvidia).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a list of the currently available miners. Most of them support Linux:

### GPU

- [DiabloMiner](http://forum.bitcoin.org/index.php?topic=1721.0) -  Support: Windows, Linux, OSX Features: Long
  Polling, BFI_INT
- [poclbm](http://forum.bitcoin.org/index.php?topic=1334.0) - Support: Windows, Linux. Features: Long Polling, BFI_INT
- [hashkill](http://forum.bitcoin.org/index.php?topic=6819.0) -  Support: Linux .Features: Long Polling, BFI_INT, Auto
  Reconnect
- [Phoenix](http://forum.bitcoin.org/index.php?topic=6458.0) -  Support: Windows, Linux. Features: Long Polling,
  BFI_INT, Auto Reconnect

### CPU

- [Jgarzik](http://forum.bitcoin.org/index.php?topic=1925.0) - Support: Windows, Linux
- [Ufasoft](http://forum.bitcoin.org/index.php?topic=3486.0) - Support: Windows, Linux. Features: Long Polling,
  Failover

### FPGA

- [FPGAminer](http://forum.bitcoin.org/index.php?topic=9047.0) - Support: Windows

### Front Ends :

- [GUIMiner](http://forum.bitcoin.org/index.php?topic=3878.0) - Support: Windows, Linux. Features : poclbm, ufasoft, phoenix
  (phakt support)
- [AOCLBF](http://forum.bitcoin.org/index.php?topic=10264.0) (Formerly Phoenix Rising) -  Support: Windows. Features:
  Phoenix (phakt support)
- [Diablo and RPC for Mac](http://forum.bitcoin.org/index.php?topic=8994.0) -  Support: OSX 10.6+ Features: CLI
  Frontend Setup
- [BitMiner](http://forum.bitcoin.org/index.php?topic=12135.0) - http://forum.bitcoin.org/index.php?topic=12135.0
  Support: Windows Features: poclbm, (Planned) Temp readings / usage

Taken from [here](http://forum.bitcoin.org/index.php?topic=16125.0). Personally, I am using the GUI minner (which has the poclbm backend). It was easy to setup and it's running fine at Ubuntu 10.10 64 bit with an ATI card.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, Linux is far better supported by the Bitcoin community than Windows is.  The same goes for ATI vs. Nvidia; ATI cards are far better at doing the calculations required for mining bitcoins, so all the serious miners use them.  32 vs. 64 bit should also be a non-issue; just pick the 64-bit version of the AMD Stream SDK instead of the 32-bit version.

[Here's a guide](http://forum.bitcoin.org/?topic=7514.0) for setting up the Phoenix and poclbm miners on Ubuntu 11.04.  Setup should be roughly similar on other distributions.